# Python: validating an instance of date

Tags: python

I am trying to do a check if a variable is of type date using the below function:

```
from datetime import date, datetime
def verify_date_dt(in_date):
    f_date = in_date
    return isinstance(f_date, datetime.date)
```

I am calling this function from another file to check a date value -

```
in_date = date(2021,4,21)
print(verify_date_dt(in_date))
```

Am getting the below error -

```
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types.
```

Would appreciate help.
I am using Python 3.6.4

Comment: Also note, `f_date = in_date` isn't doing anything meaningful. All it's doing is creating a second name for the `in_date` object.

Comment: `type(f_date) is date ` ?

Comment: @Carcigenicate, I am using f_date as variable within the function and the objective is to keep the input variables, function variables separate.

Comment: You've already created a variable called `in_date` as a parameter of the function, which is shadowing the `in_date` outside of the function. Those are two different variables both called `in_date`. It's not a big deal, I just thought I'd mention it since it doesn't serve any purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You imported `datetime.date` as `date`, and you imported `datetime.datetime` as `datetime`. So when you write `datetime.date` you end up with the `date()` method of `datetime.datetime` (which is, as the error complains, not a type).

Instead just write `isinstance(f_date, date)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import date
def verify_date_dt(in_date):
    f_date = in_date
    return isinstance(f_date, date)


in_date = date(2021,4,21)
print(verify_date_dt(in_date))

Output:
True
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your answer to include an explanation of the code you included. This will improve the quality of your answer, and make it easier for people to find it and upvote it :)